# git: recover local file overwritten by a checkout

Tags: git, macos

Consider a local file in a git repo called `foo/bar.js`. The file has been changed locally, and was accidentally overwritten by a previous commit:

```
$ git log foo/bar.js

commit 052b65bdf19ee4c977ce4d07e9d6fda60a793e0c
Author: Adam Matan (adam@example.com)
Date:   Sun May 21 16:47:22 2017 +0300

...

$ git checkout 052b65bdf19ee4c977ce4d07e9d6fda60a793e0c foo/bar.js
```

Local changes seem to be lost, as the local file is overwritten by the checkout, and has no track in the git repo. Am I missing a way to recover the file?

Comment: Did you add the file to the index before accidentally checking it out?

Comment: No `add`s or `commit`s were made

Comment: Then this is effectively equivalent to running `rm foo/bar.js`. Check https://superuser.com/questions/487234/can-files-deleted-with-rm-rf-be-recovered

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to be sure I'm right and help future readers. Care to post it as an answer so I can accept?